# PHP redirect to page with variable in URL

Tags: php, get, include

I have a page, `q.php`, that is a user submitted post defined by its id, (for example, `q.php?id=1` would be a certain post that uses the `$id` variable to pull all the rest of the information from the database).

I am trying to code a comment submission on the same page, and account for the fact that a user might not enter anything into the field. If this happens, I want the page (e.g. `q.php?id=1`) to load again with an error message.

I can do the error message with an empty variable that is then given a value by the php file that the form activates. However, I am having a problem navigating back to the specific post. I tried to use `include('q.php?id=$id)` where $id is set to a number, but I understand that this is not its purpose and it does not accept variables

What should I be using instead?

**EDIT**

answer.php (file that the form activates):

```
require 'q.php';
$_GET['id'] = $id;
$_SESSION['error'] = "Please fill in all of the fields.";
```

q.php:

```
if ($_SESSION['error'] !== 0) {
    echo "<p style='color: #AA1111;'>".$_SESSION['error']."</a>";
    unset($_SESSION['error']); // this isn't happening...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you really must include the page inline, you can always modify `$_GET`:

```
$_GET['id'] = $id;
require 'q.php';
```

But an error message sounds like it could be accomplished with a session variable or a redirect. A redirect could look something like:

```
header('Location: q.php?id=' . $id . '&error=The+error');
exit();
```

Then, you check for `$_GET['error']` in `q.php`. Using a session variable for that would be much the same, except instead of adding `error` as a querystring parameter, you use `$_SESSION['error']` and `unset` it immediately.

Comment: Thanks, this is almost perfect. I'm just having problems unsetting the session variable. Where do I do this?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Is the code  unset($_SESSION['error']); ?

Comment: @Sebastian: Yep. Have you used `session_start();` on both pages? (Or is the problem that it's showing up, but not getting unset?)

Comment: Sorry yes, the problem is that it won't disappear, so it appears on every q.php page that is subsequently loaded.

Comment: @Sebastian: Hm... are you calling `exit()` before it, or something? Can you post a small section of the code?

Comment: @Sebastian: Does the actual error message show up, or just an empty box? An undefined variable is `!== 0`; try just `if(isset($_SESSION['error']))` instead.

Comment: How weird. It works except for in order to display the message, I have to visit answer.php twice...

Comment: @Sebastian: How are you setting it in `answer.php`, and how are you redirecting?

Comment: @Sebastian: Ah, you probably shouldn’t `require 'q.php';`, then; redirect to it instead. (If that’s not the desired effect, moving the `require` line to *after* you set the session variable should work too.)

Comment: That redirects me to q.php which is blank because there's no variable.

Comment: @Sebastian: Set the session variable before redirecting, and you still need to pass the `id` parameter along with the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `header("Location: q.php?id=$id"); exit;`, but you would need some other way to send the error message (example: save it in `$_SESSION`)

You might be able to set the `$_GET` array how you want it - in this case, `$_GET = Array("id"=>$id);` then `include("q.php")`. This is generally considered haxy, though, and may result in problems if you don't use `include_once` properly.