# Execute php before redirect in a wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code thrown into a wordpress template page, which works, but how can I execute this link (with its loaded PHP paramaters) on page load instead of on click?

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 

echo ('<a href=https://portal.pension-resources.com/sso?u='.
$current_user->user_email .'>PRI LINK</a>');

?>
```

Comment: raw php: `header('Location: '.$current_user->user_email.'')`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton kind of different as OP is asking to do it in wordpress and adding current wp user as a GET parameter.

Comment: @williamli We don't focus on individual scenarios as whole new questions here. The post I linked explains how to do a redirect in PHP, adding a GET variable to that is very very simple, and can be answered from another post I'm sure, such as [PHP redirect to page with variable in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007750/php-redirect-to-page-with-variable-in-url). Individual scenarios are not usually helpful to future readers, therefore this question would be off-topic as it has already been answered.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton how about the fact that `wp_redirect` should be used over a raw header redirect?

Comment: @williamli My apologies, it appears to be more a duplicate of [Create WordPress Page that redirects to another URL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109094/wp-redirect-and-sending-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php


if (!isset($_GET["u"])) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 

    //check to see if u is the same as current user's email
    if ($current_user->user_email !== $_GET['u']) {
        wp_redirect("https://portal.pension-resources.com/sso?u=".$current_user->user_email);
        exit;
    }
}
```

ideally, you will need to wrap this header redirect function inside a if condition check to prevent an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`wp_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/)

```
wp_redirect( $url );
exit;
```